# go-redis HGETALL protobuf message

Tags: go, go-redis

Hi has anyone tried storing redis hash as proto marshalled and unmarshall and retrieve in struct? I am facing issue in that.
Doing below but not able to get desired result

1. defining an interface
2. Execution HGETALL and trying to get result in above interface
3. converting to byte array
4. parsing it to required struct

Note: using `redis.NewClusterClient` from `github.com/go-redis/redis/v8`

```
    var res interface{}
    res, err = redis.GoRedisInstance().Do(context.Background(), "HGETALL", key).Result()
    if err != nil {
    return nil, false, err
    }
    if response, ok := res.(string); ok {
    value = []byte(response)
    }
    styleEntry, err := parseStyle(ctx, value)
```

```
    func parseStyle(ctx context.Context, b []byte) (*style_fetch.CMSStyleRedisEntry, error) {
    // convert to product redis object
    productRedis := style_fetch.CMSStyleRedisEntry{}
    err := proto.Unmarshal(b, &productRedis)
    if err != nil {
    return nil, err
    }
    return &productRedis, nil
    }
```

While debugging
`redis.GoRedisInstance().Do(context.Background(), "HGETALL", key)`
I see `interface{}([]interface{})`
key - `interface{}(string)`
value(proto marshalled) - `interface{}(string)`
Attached snapshot
But .Result gives (unreadable could not resolve interface type) for both
[image]

It works for HGET though
`res, err = redis.GoRedisInstance().Do(context.Background(), "HGET", key, "style").Result()`

````
style := style_fetch.Style{}
    err := proto.Unmarshal(b, &style)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    productRedis := &style_fetch.CMSStyleRedisEntry{Style: &style}
    return productRedis, nil```
````

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved**

proto unmarshall required at invidual field level and not on whole struct as here we do hset/hmset individual fields

```
unboxed, ok := res.(map[string]string)
if !ok {
    fmt.Println("Output should be a pointer of a map")
}
//If error is nil but value is also empty/nil. Data not found in redis, reindex
if unboxed == nil || len(unboxed) <= 0 {
    //async reindexing call
    isCacheMiss = true
    statsd.Instance().Incr("redis.keyNotPresentError", 1)
    return nil, isCacheMiss, nil
}

redisEntry := &style_fetch.CMSStyleRedisEntry{}
for key, value := range unboxed {
    if key == "style" {
        style := &style_fetch.Style{}
        proto.Unmarshal([]byte(value), style)
        redisEntry.Style = style
    } 
           //...other keys
}
```